# Can memcpy Cpp function be used to copy data between system memory and gpu memory?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I know that this can be done by using cudaMemcpy, but I would like to know if memcpy can do this too.

Comment: No, `memcpy` doesn't understand the GPU memory address, it's abstracted from you. Even if you were to inspect the memory address it's meaningless to you as it has to be translated to the GPU memory address space and this requires the nvidia debugger

Comment: If GPU using host memory with OpenCL - then yes :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming modern operating systems and non-embedded hardware, `memcpy` simply copies a memory area into another, which has to be in your process' virtual address space and has no knowledge of GPUs or any other hardware.

Therefore, the only way `memcpy` may work for that purpose is if your GPU drivers mapped some pages of your address space so that writes into those pages end up going into GPU memory.

Answer (score 2):

In CUDA, if the memory is allocated using a host-mapped API such as `cudaHostAlloc`, or using a Unified Memory API such as `cudaMallocManaged`, then the pointer returned by such functions can be used directly in a C-standard-library `memcpy` operation.  The data so copied will be visible to device code using that same pointer.

A pointer returned by e.g. `cudaMalloc` cannot successfully participate in a `memcpy` operation.